# sorting through a file/returning info

Tags: c++

Just need general project help.
Basically I need to do this for 8 players. The numbers come from a file im supposed to call in. The first 5 numbers for for the first 5 games, the next for rebounds, and then for blocks. Im assuming I need to call in a loop to read the first name, last name, points, rebounds and blocks, process that info and then output the information.Any tips/ suggestions?

ex from the text file:

```
Thomas Robinson 17 28 10 16 10 11 12 13 8 9 1 1 1 0 1
```

ex from what I'm supposed to return that information to

```
         Game Log 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

 Player Name : Thomas Robinson 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Game #     Points       Rebounds       Blocks 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
   1    17    11    1 
   2    28    12    1 
   3    10    13    1 
   4    16    8    0 
   5    10    9    1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? What has given you problems?

Comment: The teacher wont let us call pre-defined functions so we have to create our own. Using an array and loop. Right now i'm working on getting an array set up to load the name of the players and to insert there stats into the table.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is homework, but since I don't know which functions can be used, and which functions can't, my answers may be can't fit the request.

At a first look, I got three ideas.

1) using `ifstream::get()`

```
ifstream in_file;
in_file.open("your_file_name.txt");
char ch;
string str = "";
while(in_file.get() != '\n')
{
  str = "";
  while((ch = in_file.get()) != ' ')
  {
    // add ch to str.
    str += string(&ch, 1);
  }
  // push str into an array, vector, stack, etc.
  /*...*/
}
in_file.close();
```

2) read the line into a `string`, and then use a `split` function, you can find how to implement a `split` function everywhere.

3) use the `ifstream::getline()` function, it provides a delemiter parameter.

you can find the usage of `ifstream::get()` and `ifstream::getline()` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

The code I provide in 1) is probably not a good practice, you should check the 'EOF' stream error, `in_file.open()`'s exceptions etc.

btw, the code I first wrote was an error code, you can't use `str += string(ch)`, you should either write `str += string(&ch, 1)` or `str += string(1, ch)` or `str += ch` you can find `string`'s constructors [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string). Sorry for the error code again.

Comment: `str += string(ch);` Really? Also, you don't handle unexpected EOF (or other stream errors) correctly.

Comment: Appreciate the help, im looking into implementing this right now. I'll let you know how it goes shortly.

Comment: @Josh Umm... the code is not properly verified, just providing a way to fix the problem.

Comment: @Josh fixed the `str+= string(ch)` bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the file with the ">>" operator pretty nicely if everything is separated by spaces and newlines. Which is how the ">>" operator works. So, yes, you need a loop. Basically you want the loop to work like this:

(I never knew you could do this in Comp Sci 1. It would've saved me so much trouble...I used to do things like what the other answer is doing.)

(I'm also assuming you know how to open a txt file as an ifstream. If not, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/open/.)

```
int temp;
int n = 0;
int x = 1;

while(textfile >> temp) // Each time through the loop, this will make temp 
                        // the next value in the file. It will stop when 
                        // there's nothing more to read.
{
    /* Now it's going to go from left to right through the file, so you 
       need some logic to put it in the right place. you know that every 
       five numbers start a new column, so:*/

    array[x][n] = temp; //Start x at 1 because you're skipping the first column
    n++;
    if (n == 5) {
        n = 0;
        x++; //Every five values, move on to the next column
    }
```

Now your array will have the stuff where it needs to be. Just output it according to plan.